# Access dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, dom

```
var $singleMember = '<a class="singleMember"><img class="avatar"><p class="username"></p></a>';

$singleMember.attr('href',member.link);
$singleMember.children('.avatar').attr('src',member.avatar);
$singleMember.children('.username').html(member.name);
```

Why does this throw "undefined is not a function"?

Comment: because you forgot to wrap your html in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var $singleMember` is just a string and therefore `.attr()` and `.children()` will not work (hence the error you are seeing)

switch it to:

```
   var singleMember = '<a class="singleMember"><img class="avatar"><p    class="username"></p></a>';
   var $singleMember = $(singleMember);

   $singleMember.attr('href',member.link);
   $singleMember.children('.avatar').attr('src',member.avatar);
   $singleMember.children('.username').html(member.name);
```

Comment: oh yes, of course... I think it's also ok to do 

var $singleMember = $('<a class="singleMember"><img class="avatar"><p class="username"></p></a>');